Desestructurando un objeto por prop en react JS
nuevo en react.
No puedo acceder a los valores que me trae un objeto
export const MouseProvider = ({ mouse, children }) => {

console.log(mouse) // veo perfecto el objeto por consola,

const {id, name, state} = mouse //error aca, cuando lo desestructuro me da error, no puede leer las variables

y si por ejemplo hago
const [mouseForm, setMouseForm]=useState(mouse)

console.log(mouseForm) 

//me trae el objeto vacio del otro componente
No se si es un problema de desestructuracion o necesito usar alguna otra funcion
gracias!!

Me parece que tienes un objeto anidado, se puede acceder a la propiedad explícitamente durante la destructuración, pero sería bueno que incluyeras lo que arroja el console para mouse

Agrega lo que te arroja el console.log(mouse) cuando lo pasas como props, como en el primer ejemplo

El problema es seguramente como estas pasando las props al componente a la hora de renderizarlo... la desestructuracion esta bien, pero si 'mouse' no es lo que debe ser, entonces no funcionara... para que funcione tenes que pasar una unica propiedad 'mouse' como un objeto al componente, tal que asi:
<Mouse mouse={{ id: Math.random() * 1000, name: 'a_name', state: true }}></Mouse>

Entonces tanto la prop como el estado que se basa en la prop se imprimirán bien.

Esta respuesta tiene sentido, ¿Porque se voto negativo?

@g.4 no tengo idea, la respuesta es breve porque el problema es sencillo de arreglar y no creo que necesite mucha mas explicacion... Tampoco se puede ver quien dio el downvote asi que me da igual ‍♂️

Gracias, es la que me sirvió, enviando los valores separados los pude desestructurar perfectamente, Gracias!!

@Zombi que bueno que lograste avanzar, sugiero que le des tu voto a la respuesta y la aceptes si te fue de ayuda, de esta forma el sitio se mantiene bien documentado, infinit3Loop parece que hay algún usuario troll haciendo mal uso de los votos negativos, yo también he estado recibiendo votos negativos...
